# Loading weighted graph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import a weighted graph from graphUnioned.csv shown below in Neo4j:
[image]

In the above graph only my p is weighted and denotes edge weights(e.g. 1.361, 3.76. etc). s and o denote the Node names namely: 431, 9812, 18558, 75, 10122, 10144, 10289, 10304.

For loading the csv file I am using:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (s:Node {value:csvLine.s}) 
MERGE (o:Node {value:csvLine.o}) 
MERGE (s)-[:REL {weight: csvLine.p}]->(o) 
RETURN *;
```

Then I am running page rank on it using:

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('node', 'REL', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85, weightProperty: "weight"})
YIELD node, score;
```

However neither the loaded graph nor the page rank algorithm seems to be running on weighted graph. Can someone please help me find as to where am I going wrong

Answer (score 3):

Node labels are case sensitive. Your nodes have the label, `Node`. So you have to pass `Node` (not `node`) as the first argument to `algo.pageRank.stream()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the weight as a float.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (s:Node {value:csvLine.s}) 
MERGE (o:Node {value:csvLine.o}) 
MERGE (s)-[:REL {weight: toFloat(csvLine.p)}]->(o);
```

Comment: Still it does not seem to be loading edge weights

Comment: What makes you say it doesnt load weights?

Comment: Because a graph without weights and a graph with weights is giving the same page rank. Which page rank algorithm does neo4j use?

Comment: Is my representation of graph incorrect. Here 1.3619 represents that move from s to o takes 1.3619 hours. I have the exact question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626547/weighted-page-rank-graph-representation

Comment: I get this error Cannot merge node using null property value for value