# Weighted page rank graph representation

Tags: python, algorithm, neo4j

I have a graph like:

```
(A, 900, B) //implying it takes 900 hours to move from task A to task B
(B, 800, C) // implying it takes 800 hours to move from B to C.
```

Now I assume in my page rank algorithm task C should have higher page rank. But it is not happening. I am using Neo4j's page rank algorithm to import the graph. My question is am I representing the graph in an incorrect way.

I think this is a general problem of representing graphs and calculating page ranks based on them.

Should I represent the graph as:

```
(A, 900/1700, B) //implying weight of edge is 900/1700, where 1700 is sum of edge weights
(B, 800/1700, C) // implying weight of edge is 800/1700
```

I also wrote a program in python, but the basic question is the same how to represent the edge graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the weight of the edge as the property of the relationship between the two nodes.

```
(A)-[:CONNECTED_TO {"Time" : 900 }]->(B)
```

I hope this format helps. For further application, you can refer the [docs](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/comparing-relationship-properties-within-a-path/)

Comment: Should weights be "Time":900 or "Time":900/1700?

Comment: weight of that edge only i.e. "Time":900

Comment: Do you know the source code of page rank algorithm in neo4j.

Comment: Did you check the documentation (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/page-rank/) ?

Comment: Thanks this is useful. Can you please help me with the following question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631857/loops-in-cypher. I need to iterate and find the page rank of all nodes in the graph